# Not all code paths return a value #2

Tags: c#, switch-statement, boolean

I am looking to return the `bool` containsVowel into my main method, where if a word contains a vowel it will allow it to be stored into an array. When I use the code below an error comes up over the method name saying "not all code paths return a value". I've also tried not using the for loop, as well as the char array - it works fine then but if I enter a vowel into the form it still says no vowel has been found.

```
private bool vowel(string word)
{
    bool containsVowel = false;

    char[] wordChar = word.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (wordChar[i])
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                return containsVowel = true;
                break;

            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Word must contain a vowel", "Error");
                return containsVowel = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mentally walk through your code. What will happen when this method is called with an empty string? Hint: it won't enter the loop.

Comment: Also, what will happen when this method is called with a null parameter

Comment: @Henningsson good point, but that won't cause compiler errors, but will throw a runtime exception with a very clear name.

Comment: Also, it is bad style to use `return containsVowel = true;`. It will work the same using `return true;` and makes the code easier to understand, and you can discard the now-unneeded variable.

Comment: Another also: With this code,if the first letter of the word is not a vowel, it would return false, and display the error mesaage

Comment: Also, every iteration of the loop will execute `word.ToUpper()` which is a waste of CPU cycles because you could have done it just once before the loop.

Comment: I wish there was a `homework` tag, or is there...

Comment: even when the first letter is a vowel it still returns false and displays the error

Comment: Debug your code to see what is happening. Anyway, if the first letter is a vowel it should return true,unless is a lower one.

Comment: @Pikoh - This is a compilation error so can't be debugged.

Comment: @Lee see OP comment `even when the first letter is a vowel it still returns false and displays the error `.Of course the code showed does not compile.

Comment: @ConorMcK according your 2nc command: With a "null" passed this wouldnt return anything. I guess your thoughts are on the `default`. But the `switch` is never entered as your `for` loop wouldnt be entered also because of 0-length. This cant be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Given your method has the return type `bool` instead of `void`, all code paths must return a value. The C# compiler tries to very naively evaluate all code paths to see if your method returns a value from all paths.

Your method looks like this to the compiler:

```
start
  for
    switch
      case
        return
      default
        return
end
```

The `switch` is covered alright thanks to the `default`, but the `for` is a conditional branch as well. If you pass an empty string, the `for` won't be entered (`i = 0` and `word.Length = 0`, so `i < word.Length` is false from the beginning), so *after* the `for`, there needs to be a return statement as well.

You can massively improve the code by doing the following:

```
public bool ContainsVowel(string word)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var upperCaseCharacters = word.ToUpper().ToCharArray();

    foreach (var character in upperCaseCharacters)
    {
        switch (character)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This code checks whether the string being passed is `null` or empty, and then immediately returns `false` (fail fast). Then it converts the string to upper case once, and loops over the character array with a `foreach()`, which is the preferred way to iterate over a collection anyway. Then it doesn't use an intermediate variable to store the result, as you can return `true` as soon as you encounter a vowel.

Finally, when no vowel has been encountered after iterating over all characters, the method returns false.

Then at the call site, you can do this:

```
if (!ContainsVowel(word))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Word must contain a vowel", "Error");
}
```

Because methods like this should not contain UI logic such as message boxes.

Comment: yeah the above code works, thanks for the help! and yes, I am a beginner lol

Comment: Shorter alternative: `return (word ?? "").ToUpper().Any(x => "AEIOU".Contains(x));`

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checked the first character of the string, since it jumped out of the loop if it was vowel or not. This should fix it, but for a better approach, check @Sr82's answer

```
private bool vowel(string word)
{
    bool containsVowel = false;

    char[] wordChar = word.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (wordChar[i])
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                return containsVowel = true;
            //if you find a vowel, you can return true straight away
        }
    }
    //if you dont find one, let the for loop finish. If it reaches this code you know
    //there was no vowel found and you can proceed with your error report
    MessageBox.Show("Word must contain a vowel", "Error");
    return containsVowel = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do.First, check for a null word value.Then you must convert your word to upper in order to detect all vowels, being this upper or lower. Then, you must only check for a vowel, because if one is present the method should return true.If,after checking all the letters, the method has not detected a vowel,show error message and return false :

```
private static bool vowel(string word)
{
    if (word == null) return false;
    char[] wordChar = word.ToUpper().ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (word[i])
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                return true;
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Word must contain a vowel");
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, this method always returns a value. In your code, if the word passed is empty,it would not enter the `for`loop, so it won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check whether a string contains a vowel and that's it, you can do something like this:

```
private bool vowel(string word)
{   
    return word.ToLower().Any(x => "aeiou".Contains(x));
}
```

This uses [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and specifically the [Any method](https://www.dotnetperls.com/any) to determine if the string contains any vowels. It would be good to set the string to all lower case so you can check whether a vowel is present irrespective of case.

Comment: A `string` is already an `IEnumerable<char>` and you already assume `word` is not null. Therefor, this can be shortened to `return word.Any(x => "aeiou".Contains(x));`

Comment: @Maarten - good point about `string`. However, I'll still need to ensure word is made lower case to match irrespective of case.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. A ToLower() is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This simple method should work if you can use Linq.  The `Intersect` method takes two `char` sequences and returns a sequence of `char` that exists in both of them.  The `Any` method returns true if there is anything in the sequence.

```
using System.Linq;

void Main()
{
    string s = "Word";
    if (hasVowels(s))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Word has vowels");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Word does not have vowels");
    }
}

//The `Intersect` method takes two `char` sequences and returns a sequence
//of `char` that exists in both of them.  The `Any` method returns true if
//there is anything in the resulting sequence.
private bool hasVowels(string word)
{
    string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    return word != null && word.Intersect(vowels).Any();
}
```